# Downloading and Accessing PDF from Firebase in Android App

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I'm currently working on an Android app, and in the initial activity, I aim to download a PDF file from Firebase. Subsequently, I wish to enable users to access specific chapters of this PDF by clicking on them. How can I implement this feature? Additionally, I'd like the app to function offline after downloading the PDF. Could you guide me through achieving these functionalities?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.